# Configure the path where Elasticsearch indexes are stored with Flask-Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask

Flask-Elasticsearch doesn't document how to configure Elasticsearch.  How can I specify the path for the storage of the indices with Elasticsearch?

```
from flask.ext.elasticsearch import FlaskElasticsearch

app = Flask(__name__)
es = FlaskElasticsearch(app)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keyword args passed to `init_app` are [passed on](https://github.com/chiangf/Flask-Elasticsearch/blob/0.2.5/flask_elasticsearch.py#L23) to the `Elasticsearch` instance.  The [Elasticsearch docs](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.0/api.html#elasticsearch) describe the options that can be passed.  Pass a different [`Indices`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.0/api.html#indices) instance to `indices`.

```
es = FlaskElasticsearch(app, indicies=MyIndicesClass())
```

As far as I can tell, there's no option to change a path, but this is how you would customize the indices.